# What is java equivalent of null assigned to var in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java

In my JS file I have

```
var previousChar = null;
```

now I manually ported the code in Java but I am getting error that character can not be assigned null.

Also is using '\0' is equal or not?

Here is the code in js-

```
previousChar=null;
nextChar=null;

var str='abc';
previousChar='a';
nextChar='c';
```

In Java it should be like this, but it gives error

```
previousChar = null;
```

Comment: `char` is a primitive type, it cannot be assigned `null`. And why do you need to do this anyway?

Comment: (XY problem?) Don't infer a language based on another language. You don't know what `A=1` does in Jelly.

Comment: @UnholySheep I am trying to manually port a 250 line code in js to java .I need that.

Comment: @RahulChoubey You need to `1` learn Java, `2` understand the code logic, and `3` rewrite it in Java.

Comment: There isn't such mechanism in Java, but to provide valid alternative it would be nice to know more about context, like how this is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare the variable as char without assigning it to null value:

```
char previous;
char next;
String str;
```

and then:

```
str = "abc";
previous = 'a';
next = 'c';
```

this will work.

The error you had was due to the fact that primitive types are handled in a different way than "real" objects are. They cannot be set to null and that means that you can't do something like:

```
Long longObject = null;
long longPrimitive = longObject;
```

this would throw a NullPointerException;

Comment: This is good but there are conditions in program where char is assigned null like we do assign null to string in java when required somewhere in code.

Comment: Then you shoud use class Character instead of char.

Comment: @RahulChoubey then you need to understand **why** there is `null` assigned to these variables, what does this null mean/indicate. And then you need to port the logic to java; not the code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign `null` to a `char` variable because `char` is a primitive type.

What you have to do is to check the code you're porting on if there are some checks on `previousChar` or `nextChar`.

If there are no checks (nothing like `if (previousChar === null)`), you may probably leave `previousChar` and `nextChar` uninitialized in Java.

But most probably there are some checks, otherwise variables would not have been initialized with `null`. In this case you'll need to port that logic to java as well. Either use some value as a replacement for `null` (for instance `0`), or use additional boolean variables. Finally, you can use the `Character` wrapper type instead of `char`, but that's overhead.

Answer (score -2):

both static and instance members of reference type not explicitly initialized are set to null by Java.you must have assign some values to your var variable rather null.

```
   char previous;
    previous="pre"
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. First, a primitive `char` variable cannot be assigned `null`. Next, in your code snippet you declare a `char` variable and assign a string to it. This does not even compile.